# The D in the DApp? Decentralised vs Distributed

Tags: dapps

Understand that the D in the DApp is decentralised. I saw some whitepapers put the D as distributed such as the flight chain whitepaper.

What is the precise difference between decentralised and distributed?

To me the term distributed still has the element of centralised control. I.e., distributed computing. Anything other differences between distributed and decentralised?